# Replace unique values of a column by a vector of new values

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with three columns: two to identify the individual, and one that corresponds to the individual's answer to a question. In this example, the answers are coded from 1 to 3 (as characters) and may contain `NA`. I would like to replace these values with their true meaning.

```
library(tibble)

my_data <- tibble(
  first_id = rep(1:2, each = 4),
  second_id = rep(rep(letters[1:2], 2), each = 2),
  variable = as.character(c(2, 1, NA, 2, 3, 1, 3, NA))
)

# A tibble: 8 x 3
  first_id second_id variable
     <int> <chr>     <chr>   
1        1 a         2       
2        1 a         1       
3        1 b         NA      
4        1 b         2       
5        2 a         3       
6        2 a         1       
7        2 b         3       
8        2 b         NA
```

The value may have a different meaning according to:

- the `first_id` column, i.e 1 may be `Yes` if `first_id` is equal to 1 and it can be `maybe` if `first_id` is equal to to 2.
- the `second_id` column.

To visualize more easily, think that this dataframe corresponds to survey data where `first_id` refers to different rounds and `second_id` to different countries.

Therefore, I would like to replace these values according to their `first_id` and `second_id`. I would like to replace the unique values of the column `variable` with a vector because I have a lot of different values and I think it's a better option than doing:

```
my_data$variable[(my_data$first_id == 1 & my_data$second_id == "a" & my_data$variable == "1")] <- "Something"
my_data$variable[(my_data$first_id == 1 & my_data$second_id == "a" & my_data$variable == "2")] <- "Something else"
```

etc.

I tried to do something like:

```
sort(unique(my_data$variable[(my_data$first_id == 1 & my_data$second_id == "a")])) <- c("Something", "Something else")
```

but I have the error:

> Error in sort(unique(my_data$variable[(my_data$first_id == 1 & my_data$second_id ==  : 
>     impossible de trouver la fonction "sort<-"

How can I replace unique values of a subsetted dataframe with a vector?

Expected output:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 3
  first_id second_id variable      
     <int> <chr>     <chr>         
1        1 a         Something else
2        1 a         Something     
3        1 b         NA            
4        1 b         2             
5        2 a         3             
6        2 a         1             
7        2 b         3             
8        2 b         NA
```

Comment: Can you show your expected output?

Comment: sure, I added it

Comment: Something like this? `my_data %>%
  mutate(variable = case_when(first_id == 1 & second_id == 'a' & variable == 2 ~ 'Something else', 
                              first_id == 1 & second_id == 'a' & variable == 1 ~ 'Something', 
                              TRUE ~ variable))
`

Comment: Not exactly, I was wondering if we could replace all (sorted) values with a vector, so that we don't have to add a line in `case_when` for each possible value in `variable`

Comment: Where are the values to replace ("Something else" and "Something") stored? Do you mean 2 in `variable` should always be replaced with "Something else" and 1 should always be replaced with "Something" ?

Comment: I mean that when first_id == 1 and second_id == 'a', 2 should always be replace by "Something else" and 1 should always be replaced by "Something". Therefore your preivous suggestion works but I find that the method is not ideal since, for all values to replace (1 and 2 in my example), you have to add a line. I was wondering if it was possible to replace all values  (1 and 2 here) with their new one ("Something" and "Something else here) in only one line

Comment: Sure but you don't have that mapping stored anywhere that when id = 1 and second_id = 'a' replace 2 with "Something else" and 1 with "else" similarly for id = 2. You should create such mapping table and join `my_data` with it then.

Comment: sorry but isn't that going to be as long as replacing old values by new ones with your first method? Could you show me what you mean with my example?

Comment: exactly, it is going to be long especially if you have more such conditions. The reason being there is no other shortcut/logic to replace values.